# Getting system.time or replicate work with piping %>%

Tags: r, dplyr, piping, magrittr

I tend to use the piping operator a lot (`%>%`, from `magrittr`, or `dplyr` library). Until one day I tried to use the `system.time` command on the right-hand-side.

```
system.time(mean(rnorm(1E7))) # ok
#### user     system      elapsed 
#### 3.52        0.05        3.58 
rnorm(1E7) %>% mean %>% system.time # ?
#### user     system      elapsed 
#### 0        0        0
```

So I went reading the documentation and I tried this (it says you can force the evaluation of RHS first by enclosing it in parenthesis, but it gives the same behaviour:

```
rnorm(1E7) %>% mean %>% (function(x) system.time(x))
#### user     system      elapsed 
#### 0        0        0
```

**My question is the following:**

**1.** Why exactly is the command `system.time` not working as expected when placed at the end of a piping line?

**2.** Is there a way to measure the calculation time of a line of code composed of pipings, without having to place the whole line inside parenthesis (which would annihilate the practical benefits of piping...) or using proc.time?

*Note*: same issue with the `replicate` command.

Comment: Not a [r] guru, But there's some tech notes at the end of the pipe (`%>%`) docs that mentions that the pipe is not exactly same as function calls. The exact wordings are *The technical notes on the %>% help may be useful: The magrittr pipe operators use non-standard evaluation. They capture their inputs and examines them to figure out how to proceed. First a function is produced from all of the individual right-hand side expressions, and then the result is obtained by applying this function to the left-hand side.*. This might be helpful to you.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao thanks, but that sounded a little bit like chinese to me ;-)

Comment: The `%>%` passes the *evaluated* result of the lhs expression and *not* the expression itself. So in the second case it's like if you gave `a<-rnorm(1E7);d<-mean(a);system.time(d)`.

Comment: @nicola all right, I get it now: it always gonna give 0, but it's working properly... so you say there is no other way than putting the system.time before the whole line in parenthesis?

Comment: @agenis Guess so.

Comment: @nicola same exact behaviour with the `replicate` command I realize

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Second best I can do is to make a wrapper on `system.time` that takes an unevaluated expression and evaluates it, and then you have to wrap the timed expression in curly brackets and quote it when you pipe it so it isn't evaluated until my wrapper function gets its paws on it:

```
> psystime = function(e){system.time(eval(e))}
> quote({rnorm(1e7) %>%  mean}) %>% psystime
   user  system elapsed 
  0.764   0.004   0.767 
>
```

I say second best, because the best answer is simply not to do this at all. Sometimes pipes are the problem, not the solution.

Another possibility is to wrap your piped expression in quotes and feed it to a `system.time` wrapper that runs an evaluated version of its argument as text:

```
> esystime = function(e){system.time(eval(parse(text=e)))}
> "rnorm(1e7) %>%  mean" %>% esystime
   user  system elapsed 
  1.075   0.033   1.137
```

I'm guessing the use case for this is really when you have a long pipeline and want to quickly see how long it takes to run, so you naturally want to just bung `%>% system.time` on the end. Its probably just as easy, assuming you know the keyboard shortcuts for "start of line" and "end of line", to put `system.time(` on the start and `)` on the end.

Comment: There is also always the option of using pipes for everything *except* system.time. i.e `system.time(rnorm(1E7) %>% mean)`

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(106)`

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman for the extensive input. I completely agree with your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround using piping and proc.time. It's not absolutely perfect but it can be helpful. It also uses the tee operator.

First define a Timer function that counts the time from a start.time variable recorded in the global environment.

```
Timer = function(x){
  if (exists("start.time")){
    print(proc.time() - start.time)
    rm('start.time', envir=.GlobalEnv)
  } else {
    assign("start.time", proc.time(), envir=globalenv())
  }
}
```

Then use it in second place of the pipeline, and again the end of it:

```
diamonds %T>% Timer %>% group_by(clarity) %>% summarise(sd(price)) %>% Timer
#### user  system elapsed 
#### 0.02    0.00    0.02
```

You get the computation time of everything but the first element (but often it's just the data, so..). I compared with the system.time way, it doesn't seem to give much different results.